# Htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to install a Symfony based website on a shared hosting server. I can write into /www/ only.

The problem is that Symfony will be in /www/web/ ; Is there a way to serve

```
www.example.com/web/index.php/something
```

when users ask for :

```
www.example.com/index.php/something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this rule in the .htaccess file in the document root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^web/ web%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This will prepend `/web` to every request that’s path does not already start with `/web/`.

Comment: This works, but is there anyway to not add "/web/" to the url ? I'm redoing my website using symfony and I'd like to have the same urls as before, to keep my pagerank.

Comment: @Manu: This rule shouldn’t cause an external redirect. Are you using any other rules that may cause that?

Comment: @Manu: Take a look at [mod_rewrite’s logging feature](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel) to see what causes this external redirect.

Comment: Wow I don't think I can access that on the server

Comment: http://example.com/index.html serves /web/index.html, but
http://example.com/test/ rewrites the url as http://example.com/web/test/
I only have one htaccess file, maybe the server's config is weird.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [L]
```