# How to redirect url to parent directory with url rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to make redirections from a sub-directory to the parent directory.

In other words I have to redirect anything matching

```
http://exemple.com/portfolio/product1
```

to :

```
http://exemple.com/product1
```

Is there any way to do that with URL REWRITE ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Htaccess redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685413/htaccess-redirect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^portfolio/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to put this into .htaccess inside the directory that you want to be redirrected

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/parent 
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/parent
```