# Advanced 301 redirect for an entire site at site root?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla

I am struggling with an age old problem. I inherited a site with some pretty good SEO and one glaring problem. The entire site is hosted on the /site/ subdirectory. I have decided that I need to load the site at the root. So something like http://example.org/site/index.php will instead redirect to /index.php (<-- that counted as a link, if it is unclear I mean it to be the root of the site/index.php.)

We use joomla for our backend and there are hundreds of pages on the site at this point. I have struggled getting any of the redirects I have seen to do what I want them to do. Basically, any page our patrons visit from an old link with */site/* in it should be redirected to the exact same link, but without the star.

I am open to just loading the page from /site/ and making it look like it is from root. It is my understanding that this can be done with some advances mod-rewrite (http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs ?) but I have not had any success yet. I run a beta site that mimics the parent site in a subdomain that I have already moved from /site/ to / so I can test a lot of .htaccess configs.

Any help is appreciated... thanks!

Comment: I found this that seems to do the trick... 

RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.beta.example.org$ [nc]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://beta.example.org/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

Does anyone know if this code will work with the joomla url rewruting also enabled? So it can remove the /index.php/ from the page as well? Also, I am not sure how this code works, but it seems to do exactly what I need it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be sure: you want http://example.org/site/foo/bar/baz.php to go to http://example.org/foo/bar/baz.php, that is, to remove (via redirect) the /site prefix if it's there, but not touch the URL otherwise, right? If so, it depends on which server you're using:

- If your server is Apache, you could use something like this in `.htaccess`:

  ```
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/site/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1
  ```
- If it is nginx, add this to the `server {...}` session of your site's file (usually symlinked inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`):

  ```
  location ~ ^/site/(.*)$ { rewrite ^/site/(.*)$ /$1 permanent; }
  ```

[Here is a good explanation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx) on how such pattern-based redirects can be set up in both servers.

Comment: This is great.. simple.. and elegant. I have no idea why I couldn't find something link this while researching on Google. That one line in .htaccess does the trick absolutely perfectly! Are there any other things you would suggest get added to this to increase its effectivness? I was wondering about a popup after redirect that said something like "Please bookmark the new page" or something. Any ideas? 

Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Glad it is useful. Unfortunately, the redirect header will be processed immediately, so it can't really render anything. On the other hand, both configs use the `301` HTTP status, which "tells" search engines (and smart bookmark mechanisms) that the redirect is "permanent", so they will replace the old URL with the new one in their records. SEO-wise, it's the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the working answer that I will go with. Basically, this needs put into the directory that you are wanting to redirect from, in my case, that was root/site/.

---

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.beta.example.org$ [nc]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://beta.example.org/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

---

I assume the first rule ignores www? I'd love to work around that but am not sure exactly why it would have been created anyway. this will rewrite any URL that accesses that .htaccess file (inside your subdirectory) and direct you to the same URL without the subdirectory listing. It doesn't really work with the index.php rewrite tool, but that is fine because it still reaches the correct page.

If anyone has a better option for me with use with Joomla I would be glad to hear it. But, I tihnk this is what I will go with for now because it is giving me great results.

Comment: the first one doesn't ignore www; `RewriteCond` [says](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) "hey, if this matches, there's something you will need to do". The "somethinig" is the RewriteRule, of course. Your answer seems fairly incorrect based on your question. If you unaccept it I'll give a better rule.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18468916/1470907) seems more appropriate for your question. The rule in your answer effectively says: `If the domain doesn't start with 'www', redirect to a version without 'www'.` This would normally cause a redirect loop, but that's avoided here by redirecting to a location that isn't affected by this rule. You can remove the `RewriteCond` line and use a path instead of a full URL in the rule to make the intent of the rule clearer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this one. I unaccepted mine and accepted the guys answer below because his does a fantastic job. Is there a better way? I would gladly change the best answer if someone improves upon @chesterbr below. I assume his answer would also work the best with existing SEO. I accepted what I found as the answer only because it looked like it was doing what I wanted it to do though.

Answer (score 0):

if your server is apache2, you can configure there

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sitio.com
ServerAlias www.sitio.com
DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/sitio/
...
</VirtualHost>
```

You need permissions for this change